# Using lodash what is a good way of mapping data from arrays into a single array?

Tags: javascript, lodash

What is a fast way of mapping data like the data below using lodash into a single array of level2 objects.

```
    SomeObject = {
    name: 'someObject',
    level1: [
        {
            id: '1',
            level2: [
                { someValue: 'example1'},
                { someValue: 'example2'},
                { someValue: 'example3'},
                { someValue: 'example4'}
            ]
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            level2: [
                { someValue: 'example5' },
                { someValue: 'example6' },
                { someValue: 'example7' },
                { someValue: 'example8' }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 'n',
            level2: [
                { someValue: 'examplen' },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

output:

```
[
 'example1',
 'example2',
 'example3',
 'example4',
 'example5',
 'example6',
 'example7',
 'example8',
 'examplen',
]
```

ignore:
Stackflow is smarter than I so I have to type more non code stuff for it to stop complaining. So I'll type more so that I may post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flatMap()` to collect all the "level2" arrays into a single array and then extract the "someValue" properties with a simple `map()`

```
_.map(_.flatMap(SomeObject.level1, "level2"),"someValue")
```

Comment: My output was wrong and its been edited to the correct output. Sorry for the confusion! ugh its supposed to be an array of strings.

Comment: Then just add another map() to extract the someValue property.

Comment: That'll create an array of arrays and then flatten handles it. Genius. Thank you

Comment: @Calvin Now that i'm back at my computer, i've updated the answer to use `flatMap`. That basically does both the `map` and `flatten`